# XSLT - Remove duplicates, whilst adding up quantity field

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

I have an issue that can only be resolved using an XSLT. The issue is we do not want duplicate XML tags with the same Id and however in the scenario that there are multiple tags the quantity fields from both tags need adding together. This can easily be demonstrated in the below XML.

**INPUT XML**

```
<root>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
</root>
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
<root>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
</root>
```

**XSLT**

Started XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <root>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="orderLine"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/root/oderLine">
        <xsl:if test="not(sku = preceding-sibling::orderLine/sku)"> </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Compare Both Id & SKU**

Example

**Input**

```
<root>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111222</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>a
    </Line>
</root>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<root>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111222</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
</root>
```

**Actual Output**

```
<root>
    <Line>
        <Id>4</Id>
        <sku>111111</sku>
        <quantity>3</quantity>
    </Line>
    <Line>
        <Id>3</Id>
        <sku>222222</sku>
        <quantity>2</quantity>
    </Line>
</root>
```

As you can see it is only matching Id and not SKU as well.

Comment: For grouping problems you really need to say whether you are using XSLT 1.0 or XSLT 2.0. The solution with 2.0 is always much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XSLT 1.0 use [Muechian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="l-by-id" match="Line" use="Id"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line[generate-id() = generate-id(key('l-by-id', Id)[1])]/quantity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('l-by-id', ../Id)/quantity)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line[generate-id() != generate-id(key('l-by-id', Id)[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[edit]
Here is an adaption of above solution to group on both Id and sku:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="l-by-id" match="Line" use="concat(Id, '|', sku)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line[generate-id() = generate-id(key('l-by-id', concat(Id, '|', sku))[1])]/quantity">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('l-by-id', concat(../Id, '|', ../sku))/quantity)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Line[generate-id() != generate-id(key('l-by-id', concat(Id, '|', sku))[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That works apart from one scenario, if Id is the same but sku is the different. It needs to compare both. I shown an example at the bottom of the post.

Comment: I will edit and show you how to use a key composed of two element values to solve the new requirement.